# How to create singleton class when I importing it from multiple places?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I make a Singleton class if I want to import it at multiple places?

I ended up with something like this, but I am exporting a new() instance (at least I think so) at each time I import it.

```
class RenderToRootAPI {
    renderToRootComponent = null
    setRenderComponent = ref => this.renderToRootComponent = ref
    setInstance = instance =>  {
        console.warn('setting instance')
        this.renderToRootComponent.setInstance(instance)
    }
    deleteInstance = () => this.renderToRootComponent.deleteInstance
}

export default new RenderToRootAPI()
```

Comment: What you have written *will* export a singleton. It doesn't matter how many times you import it.

Comment: I think `this` used in your functions there is not the class instance though, because you are using lambda - you should use a method via `function` instead of lambda expressions

Comment: Ahh I see, I didn't know it working this way! thanks guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have written *will* export a singleton. It doesn't matter how many times you import it.

It might look a bit more clear if you write it like this as an example:

```
class RenderToRootAPI {
    renderToRootComponent = null
    setRenderComponent = ref => this.renderToRootComponent = ref
    setInstance = instance =>  {
        console.warn('setting instance')
        this.renderToRootComponent.setInstance(instance)
    }
    deleteInstance = () => this.renderToRootComponent.deleteInstance
}

const renderToRootAPI = new RenderToRootAPI();

export default renderToRootAPI;
```

The class is not even exported, and the single exported instance will be used in all the modules that import it.

Comment: Thanks Tholle! I thought the code would run down every single time I import it, and by doing that would make me a new instance. But now I think about it, that would be pretty extreme :D. Thanks again! :)